# Why an AND function in excel displays a value when the cells it depends from is blank

Tags: excel

So my formula is

```
=IF(AND(B5=B4, C5=C4), 10, "КРЪГЛА НУЛА")
```

with all of B5, B4, C5, C4 being blank, it says 10... so it assumes that its right. I want it to be blank until I get values in B5, B4, C5 and C4. How can this happen and, um, why does it get a value now?

Comment: They are all equally empty, so "right" is the correct way for it to work. You can just check whether the cells are empty with IF(A1="", "Empty", "Not Empty")

Comment: Sure, but there should be a way to make it blank before they are equal with values in them, thats 99% of my question, the important part, how can I do it? As it really gets the point lost that way

Comment: As @Secespitus wrote, you are looking for two conditions, not one.  You need to test that the cells are equal.  But you ALSO need to test that the cells are NOT blank.  Perhaps it is a language difference, but two blank (or empty) cells are `equal`.

Comment: I understand this, yeah, but I want it to be blank until there are values in *all* of the cells this formula includes, in the case B5, B4, C5, C4

EDIT: Got my answer down :)

Comment: =IF(AND(B5<>"";B4<>"";C5<>"";C4<>"");IF(AND(B5=B4, C5=C4);"10";"КРЪГЛА НУЛА");"")

Comment: Thanks Secespitus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are describing is working as designed. The cells are empty, which is represented as an empty string. At start they are all equally empty.

That means you can use multiple conditions to check whether the cells are empty and whether the cells are equal. An easy solution for this problem would be the following:

```
=IF(AND(B5<>"";B4<>"";C5<>"";C4<>"");IF(AND(B5=B4, C5=C4);"10";"КРЪГЛА НУЛА");"")
```